# Ideas to prevent files and folders from being scanned by anti viruses program

Tags: windows, security, antivirus, rootkit

I have recently began my study on rookits and bootkits as a part of my university course. I have written a very basic rootkit that allow the discovery of a NTFS filesystem.

The trouble is that after complie my antivirus (Windows Defender) immediately flags and delete the complied debug file. I know that I can add the whole folder to exclusion in WD, but just a point of interest I wonder if there is a way that I can prevent the rootkit development folder/files from being scanned by all (or most advanced) antivirus programs without having to deal with individual cases.

I have came across several methods. One is to use Folder Locks or similar programs to lock the folder on the go. This does work to some extends, but stronger antiviruses such as Kaspersky can still detect the files. I then wrote a program to turn the exe file to a NTFS Filesystem by changing MFT reference number to 12 while the code has already been loaded in VS Studio. This prevents all antiviruses from detecting the file, but at the same time disconnected the file from loading in VS Studio (Gave me data corruption), so I feel this method is a little bit too hardcore.

I also went through changing the permissions but not sure how practical it should be.

So in short, any other ideas (for educational purposes only) on preventing a file/folder from being scanned by antiviruses while still able to be used by the OS?

Apologise if the question is not clear, I do find these words a little bit confused.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to circumvent the detection of your code **from within the code** (so that it hides from AV software), or a way to make the AV not detect the code **by actions on the OS level** (the machine which hosts the code)?

Comment: I would say by action on the OS level. The reason being I am fairly new to rootkit and at the moment my rootkit is not that far advanced. It still opens a handle to the system. Also I understand that most AV these day have some form of driver on kernel level which could detect almost anything so writing a rootkit that hide itself would certainly requires of its being kernel level, unless there is a way that I have not known about.

Comment: Hello @LeoLongVu!
: " I have written a very basic rootkit that allow the discovery of a NTFS filesystem." what exactly, does it do? does it detects a NTFS filesystem (why? and where?) 

And, *maybe the following should be posted as a answer..(someone? maybe)*:
The short answer is no; because - "preventing a file/folder from being scanned by antiviruses while still able to be used by the OS? " - is most likely (**hopefully**) so impossible as possible; because (well, the obvious reasons are - it would be extremely risky) Even for edu.purposes; 

What you could do however is obfuscate it.